# Regex Expression Non Capturing Group

Tags: regex

I am trying to read out an amount on a invoice. 
The line in question (there are a few other lines that include € but not the word 'Total') looks like this: 
Total   €  31.73 
I want my full match to be only the digits (including the point) not the € symbol right in front of it.

What I tried is a non-capturing group for € but my full match still includes it.

This is the expression i tried:

```
(?<=Total)(?:[\s€]*)((((\d+)[,.]{1,10})+\d{0,2})|(\d+(?!,)))
```

Comment: which programming language? Also, does the text contain € always?

Comment: You must know what method this regex to use with. What is it?

Comment: You have a few capturing groups, but if you don't need them and the euro sign should be there then try a single capturing group without the lookbehind:  `\bTotal\s+€\s*(\d{1,10}(?:\.\d{2}))\b` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BfIkkX/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex pattern:

```
Total\s+(?:€\s)?(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)
```

The total amount would be present in the first capture group.

### Demo

Here is a brief explanation of the regex:

```
Total\s+         match "Total" followed by one or more spaces
(?:€\s)?         match an optional Euro sign, followed by a space
(                capture
    \d{1,3}      match one to three digits
    (?:,\d{3})*  followed by zero or more thousands groups
    (?:\.\d+)?   followed by an optional decimal component
)                stop capture
```

**Edit:**

If you want a pattern whose entire match is only the numeric portion, then try using this:

```
(?:(?<=Total )|(?<=Total € ))\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?
```

### Demo

This asserts that either `Total` or `Total €` comes first, followed by the number.  Note that it does *not* actually match the prefix, but only matches the number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is I need the full match to be **only** the digits. Not the "Total" not the "€".

Comment: @LumaxZ What regex tool are you using?  If you are using something like Java, PHP, C#, Perl, etc., then all you have do is use my pattern and access the _first_ capture group.

Comment: I am using software, that reads out my bank statements and invoices (OCR) and then archives them. So I'm not able to change the code to use only a specific capture group.

Comment: I have given an update with a pattern that might work for you.

Comment: It does! Thanks a lot